# How to record audio in Python without giving the duration in advance

Tags: python, pycharm, recording, pyaudio

I am writing a function to record audio in python. I used libraries like `pyaudio` to achieve the goal. But the problem is I have to give the duration of the recording as an input. Is there a way to record audio until the user wants to?

I found a way to record the audio for any duration. The problem is 'Ctrl + C' to stop the recording is not working in 'pycharm'. The code is as follows.

```
import sys
import queue
import tempfile
import numpy as np
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf
assert np


q = queue.Queue()


def callback(indata, frames, time, status):
    """
    This is called from a separate thread for each audio block
    """
    if status:
        print(status, file=sys.stderr)
    q.put(indata.copy())


# Unique file name for every recording
filename = tempfile.mktemp(prefix='untitled_', suffix='.wav', dir='')
# Make sure the file is open before recording anything
with sf.SoundFile(filename, mode='x', samplerate=48000, channels=2) as file:
    with sd.InputStream(samplerate=48000, channels=2, callback=callback):
        print('#' * 80)
        print('press Ctrl+C to stop the recording')
        print('#' * 80)
        while True:
            file.write(q.get())
```

Comment: Please add your code in your question.

Comment: Literally in the docs http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#example-blocking-mode-audio-i-o

Comment: @FHTMitchell It will be great if you can read the question once again!!

Comment: So it doesnt work in your ide? Does it work when you run it from the terminal?

Comment: @Rafael Added the code

Comment: @FHTMitchell Yes, It does work in terminal, but not in IDE.

Comment: So your question is actually -- how do i make this work in pycharm? I think that's quite a different question to the one you asked. It's also a bit off topic for stack overflow.

Comment: The "proper" way to do this in pure Python without expecting commands to kill your process in terminal is to use separate threads via `threading`. See for e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23100704/running-infinite-loops-using-threads-in-python).

Comment: thanks for your suggestions