# How do I update and retrieve an image using multiprocessing python?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

In my code I have two functions, the first function `operate_camera` updates the storage variable. The second function `print_func` prints the storage variable.

I would like to run these two functions concurrently, with the printing process happening with a delay of 15 seconds. However the `operate_camera` function contains a `while` loop. And by running the script, it will only run the process `p2` once, and will stay stuck at the process `p1`.

For simplicity, I work with simple 1D arrays in the following code.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Array 
import numpy as np 
import time

def operate_camera(store):
    while True: # loop that updates image
        store = store + np.ones_like(store)

def print_func(store):
    print(store)
    time.sleep(15)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    store = np.array([0,0,0])

    p1 = Process(target=operate_camera, args=(store,))
    p2 = Process(target=print_func, args=(store,))

    p1.start()    
    p2.start()
```

The output will simply be stuck at

```
[0,0,0]
```

Are there any solutions within the multiprocessing package that can allow me to retain this form of code. If not, are there any alternative solutions to this problem?

Comment: Have you tried getting out a clock and waiting for a full minute? Also, thanks for the [mcve]!

Comment: Since you're using multiprocessing you could have another `while` loop inside your print_func to constantly print your values and concurrently update them with `operate_camera`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do you really want multiprocessing here, instead of multithreading?
You asked for alternative solutions, so, I come up with multithreading for this problem. You should check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23100704/running-infinite-loops-using-threads-in-python) for clarity, where mostly the same problem is discussed. So, I think the problem is that your print function executes only ones, hence you also want a loop there.

```
from threading import Thread
import numpy as np
import time

store = np.array([0, 0, 0])


def operate_camera():
    while True:
        global store
        store += np.ones_like(store)


def print_func():
    while True:
        time.sleep(15)
        print(store)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    t1 = Thread(target=operate_camera)
    t2 = Thread(target=print_func)

    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    # other code

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

You can notice, that this code uses global object which is not the best practice, but we need a shared object there.

In case of functions with parameters

```
from threading import Thread
import numpy as np
import time


def operate_camera(store):
    while True:
        store += np.ones_like(store)


def print_func(store):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(store)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    store = np.array([0, 0, 0])

    camera_thread = Thread(target=operate_camera, args=(store, ))
    camera_thread.setDaemon(True)
    camera_thread.start()

    while True:
        print_func(store)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help. Will this work if I have another print function, i.e. `print_func1()`?

Comment: @Tian Yeah, create new thread as a camera_thread in the example above and combine it with the first example. Also, if this helps, you can mark the answer

Comment: Okay, I would like to check as well. With two functions accessing the same store variable at different times, coupled with the fact that the `operate_camera function` is constantly updating the store variable, will there be any error that would arise?? Also, what is the use of `camera_thread.setDaemon(True)`?