# Handling async responses immediately

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I need to parse repeatedly one link content. synchronous way gives me 2-3 responses per second, i need faster (yes, i know, that too fast is bad too)

I found some async examples, but all of them show how to handle result after all links are parsed, whereas i need to parse it immediately after receiving, something like this, but this code doesn't give any speed improvement:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time
async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()

async def main():
    while True:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            html = await fetch(session, 'https://example.com')
            print(time.time())
            #do_something_with_html(html)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: 2-3 is "too slow" but "too fast is bad also", what are you looking for?

Comment: maybe 10-20 req per sec

Comment: Similar question answered here that still makes use of `asyncio`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54156503/how-to-run-tasks-concurrently-in-asyncio/54156527#54156527

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but this code doesn't give any speed improvement

asyncio (and async/concurrency in general) gives speed improvement for I/O things that interleave each other.

When everything you do is `await something` and you never create any parallel tasks (using `asyncio.create_task()`, `asyncio.ensure_future()` etc.) then you are basically doing the classic synchronous programming :)

So, how to make the requests faster:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time

async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()

async def check_link(session):
    html = await fetch(session, 'https://example.com')
    print(time.time())
    #do_something_with_html(html)

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        while True:
            asyncio.create_task(check_link(session))
            await asyncio.sleep(0.05)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Notice: the `async with aiohttp.Cliensession() as session:` must be above (outside) `while True:` for this to work. Actually, having a single `ClientSession()` for all your requests is a good practice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up using async, threading solved my problem, thanks to this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23102874/5678457

```
from threading import Thread
import requests
import time
class myClassA(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            r = requests.get('https://ex.com')
            print(r.status_code, time.time())
for i in range(5):
    myClassA()
```