# How to run tasks concurrently in asyncio?

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, task, python-asyncio

I'm trying to learn how to run tasks concurrently using Python's asyncio module. In the following code, I've got a mock "web crawler" for an example. Basically, I am trying to make it where there are a max of two active fetch() requests happening at any given time, and I want process() to be called during the sleep() period.

```
import asyncio

class Crawler():

    urlq = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com', 
            'http://www.cnn.com', 'http://www.gamespot.com', 
            'http://www.facebook.com', 'http://www.evergreen.edu']

    htmlq = []
    MAX_ACTIVE_FETCHES = 2
    active_fetches = 0

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    async def fetch(self, url):
        self.active_fetches += 1
        print("Fetching URL: " + url);
        await(asyncio.sleep(2))
        self.active_fetches -= 1
        self.htmlq.append(url)

    async def crawl(self):
        while self.active_fetches < self.MAX_ACTIVE_FETCHES:
            if self.urlq:
                url = self.urlq.pop()
                task = asyncio.create_task(self.fetch(url))
                await task
            else:
                print("URL queue empty")
                break;

    def process(self, page):
        print("processed page: " + page)

# main loop

c = Crawler()
while(c.urlq):
    asyncio.run(c.crawl())
    while c.htmlq:
        page = c.htmlq.pop()
        c.process(page)
```

However, the code above downloads the URLs one by one (not two at a time concurrently) and doesn't do any "processing" until after all URLs have been fetched. How can I make the fetch() tasks run concurrently, and make it so that process() is called in between during sleep()?

Comment: My ultimate goal is to write an async web crawler that will be constantly fetching pages from a URL queue in background, with HTML/text processing happening concurrently with fetches. This is just mock code to learn to use asyncio ... This is why I am trying to run processing concurrently with fetching, instead of just doing it after.

Comment: Running the event loop is a blocking operation. You’ll need to make `process` a coroutine that gets scheduled with the loop or awaited by something else that is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your `crawl` method is waiting after each individual task; you should change it to this:

```py
async def crawl(self):
    tasks = []
    while self.active_fetches < self.MAX_ACTIVE_FETCHES:
        if self.urlq:
            url = self.urlq.pop()
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(self.fetch(url)))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

*EDIT*: Here's a cleaner version with comments that fetches and processes all at the same time, while preserving the basic ability to put a cap on the maximum number of fetchers.

```py
import asyncio

class Crawler:

    def __init__(self, urls, max_workers=2):
        self.urls = urls
        # create a queue that only allows a maximum of two items
        self.fetching = asyncio.Queue()
        self.max_workers = max_workers

    async def crawl(self):
        # DON'T await here; start consuming things out of the queue, and
        # meanwhile execution of this function continues. We'll start two
        # coroutines for fetching and two coroutines for processing.
        all_the_coros = asyncio.gather(
            *[self._worker(i) for i in range(self.max_workers)])

        # place all URLs on the queue
        for url in self.urls:
            await self.fetching.put(url)

        # now put a bunch of `None`'s in the queue as signals to the workers
        # that there are no more items in the queue.
        for _ in range(self.max_workers):
            await self.fetching.put(None)

        # now make sure everything is done
        await all_the_coros

    async def _worker(self, i):
        while True:
            url = await self.fetching.get()
            if url is None:
                # this coroutine is done; simply return to exit
                return

            print(f'Fetch worker {i} is fetching a URL: {url}')
            page = await self.fetch(url)
            self.process(page)

    async def fetch(self, url):
        print("Fetching URL: " + url);
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        return f"the contents of {url}"

    def process(self, page):
        print("processed page: " + page)


# main loop
c = Crawler(['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com', 
             'http://www.cnn.com', 'http://www.gamespot.com', 
             'http://www.facebook.com', 'http://www.evergreen.edu'])
asyncio.run(c.crawl())
```

Comment: Thanks dtanabe. Your solution did make the fetch() calls run concurrently, but it still postponed processing until after all of them had been fetched. How would I make it so that while downloads are happening, process() is called on whatever HTML has been put into htmlq?

Comment: Added a fuller version that also processes fetched data while other URL fetches are allowed to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `htmlq` an `asyncio.Queue()`, and change `htmlq.append` to `htmlq.push`. Then your `main` can be async, like this:

```
async def main():
    c = Crawler()
    asyncio.create_task(c.crawl())
    while True:
        page = await c.htmlq.get()
        if page is None:
            break
        c.process(page)
```

Your top-level code boils down to a call to `asyncio.run(main())`.

Once you are done with crawling, `crawl()` can enqueue `None` to notify the main coroutine that the work is done.

Comment: This would have the added bonus that, by setting the size of the queue to 2, there’s no need to track the number of concurrent fetches.

Comment: Thanks @user4815162342. I didn't know of asyncio.Queue() before, so that was helpful. But when I tried modifying the code as you suggested, I got the following error: "*RuntimeError: Task <Task pending coro=<Crawler.crawl() running at testasync.py:39> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py:158]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop*" ... I'm not sure if I need to modify crawl() somehow to work with your code, or what is happening, but it appears that something is failing on the line "page = await self.htmlq.get()" ... any ideas?

Comment: @J.Taylor The problem is that `Queue()` needs to be instantiated in the same event loop that it will be run in, and each `asyncio.run()` creates a _new_ event loop. In your case the fix is to just move the `Crawler` instantiation to a coroutine; I've now edited the answer accordingly.