# How to run DASH in async with asyncio

Tags: plotly-dash, python-asyncio

Has anyone successfully manage running a Dash app using aysncio for Python?
Any examples greatly appreciated.
I have been digging deep into the event loop, co-routines and tasks in asyncio.
Essentially I want to do this:

```
main_loop()

1. ASYNC - Collect data from web (async call / avoid blocking)
2. ASYNC - Process data (when data is collected from task1)
3. ASYNC - Update data (when data processed from task2) 
4. Display Data using Dash (this should be running constantly of status task 1,2 and 3)
```

So - how to communicate between tasks, and run the Display (DASH) seperately?
Ideas:
- 2 event loops
- Two thread?
Issues:
- How to communicate between tasks
- How to run the DASH app the whole time whilst the event_loop above also repeats forever / until interrupted (i.e. getData, ProcessData, UpdateDashDisplay...)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54156503/how-to-run-tasks-concurrently-in-asyncio mentions that "Running the event loop is a blocking operation. You’ll need to make process a coroutine that gets scheduled with the loop or awaited by something else that is." - Any examples of how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a 'Display' task continuously within an asyncio Event Loop where data is collected occasionally via asyncio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57887867/how-to-run-a-display-task-continuously-within-an-asyncio-event-loop-where-data)

Answer (score 1):

Dash App in Async ->

Please refer to:

[Asyncio run Dash (Flask) server with another coroutine concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67206119/asyncio-run-dash-flask-server-with-another-coroutine-concurrently/68724732#68724732)

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import asyncio
from threading import Thread


# Dash
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import requests
import plotly.graph_objects as go 


# ** Async Part **

async def some_print_task():
    """Some async function"""
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print("Some Task")


async def another_task():
    """Another async function"""
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        print("Another Task")


async def async_main():
    """Main async function"""
    await asyncio.gather(some_print_task(), another_task())


def async_main_wrapper():
    """Not async Wrapper around async_main to run it as target function of Thread"""
    asyncio.run(async_main())


# *** Dash Part ***:
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([

    # html.Div([
    #     html.Iframe(src="https://www.flightradar24.com",
    #                 height=500,width=200)
    # ]),
    html.Div([
        html.Pre(id='counter-text',children='Active Flights Worldwide'),
        dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph',style={'width':1200}),
        dcc.Interval(   id='interval-component',
                        interval=6000,
                        n_intervals=0)
    ])
])
counter_list = []

@app.callback(  Output('counter-text','children'),
                [Input('interval-component','n_intervals')])
def update_layout(n):
    url = "https://data-live.flightradar24.com/zones/fcgi/feed.js?faa=1&mlat=1&flarm=1&adsb=1&gnd=1&air=1&vehicles=1&estimated=1&stats=1"
    res = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})  # A fake header is necessary to access the site
    data = res.json()
    counter = 0
    for element in data["stats"]["total"]:
        counter += data["stats"]["total"][element]

    counter_list.append(counter)
    return "Active flights Worldwide: {}".format(counter)

@app.callback(  Output('live-update-graph','figure'),
                [Input('interval-component','n_intervals')])
def update_graph(n):
    fig = go.Figure(data=[
            go.Scatter(x=list(range(len(counter_list))),
                        y=counter_list,
                        mode='lines+markers')
    ])

    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run all async stuff in another thread
    th = Thread(target=async_main_wrapper)
    th.start()
    app.run_server(debug=True)
    th.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar requirement where I want to run dash and its callbacks asynchronously. So I created this library called [async-dash](https://github.com/snehilvj/async-dash). With this you can use truly asynchronous callbacks as well as web sockets, SSE, etc.

Example:

```py
import asyncio

from async_dash import Dash
from dash import html, Output, Input, dcc, callback

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = ...

@callback(...)
async def create_dashboard(...):
    await fetch_data()
    result await process_data()
    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

PS: Don't use it for production (just yet!).

Comment: I look forward to trying this. Many thanks! I sent another approach ->

Answer (score -2):

This may work. Just create an async function for the data collection, processing and updating. Then create another async function for the dash code. Then run it like below:

```
async def web_data():
    # web data code goes here

async def dash_code():
    # Dash code goes here

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(web_data(), dash_code())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Within web data there needs to be breakdown as per Question. Task 1 is calling data from web server. Only then do I process (task2) and update to Database (task3) -- Then Dash should be constantly running, I know how to chain tasks. But would my Question be solved by just using gather rather than event loops/threads ( also as said I need to chain task2 (process data) until data has arrived from a remote server. I worry about how to communicate status between tasks using your proposed use of gather? Is there enough control there? Thks.

Comment: Any progress on this? Is this doable?