# Asyncio run Dash (Flask) server with another coroutine concurrently

Tags: python, flask, concurrency, python-asyncio, plotly-dash

I created a dash app to present information that another code is collecting, I want to run them both concurrently using the asyncio module in Python.

My code is using async functions and the Dash app (which is based on Flask) is blocking anything else from executing while serving.

I'm not sure if this is something that has to involve opening up more threads.

Here's my current code which only runs the main coroutine.

```
async def main():
    some code here...

    while True:
        try:
            await client.handle_message()
        except ConnectionClosedError as error:
            logger.error(error)
    
        for strategy in strategies:
            await asyncio.create_task(...)
            some code here...

async def run_dashboard():
    app = create_app()
    app.run_server('0.0.0.0', 5000, debug=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    some code here...

    # Currently just runs the main coroutine
    asyncio.run(main())
```

How can I run main and run_dashboard concurrently?

Comment: Any feedback please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Frankly speaking it is **not good design** to combine Dash (Flask) with some async work in one process, consider to run Flask and async activities in different processes (i.e. apps).

Nevertheless, If you still want to run all in one process, I can give you the following **working example**, please follow comments and ask if you have any questions:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import asyncio
from threading import Thread

# ** Async Part **


async def some_print_task():
    """Some async function"""
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print("Some Task")


async def another_task():
    """Another async function"""
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        print("Another Task")


async def async_main():
    """Main async function"""
    await asyncio.gather(some_print_task(), another_task())


def async_main_wrapper():
    """Not async Wrapper around async_main to run it as target function of Thread"""
    asyncio.run(async_main())

# *** Flask Part ***:


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    """just some function"""
    return jsonify({"hello": "world"})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run all async stuff in another thread
    th = Thread(target=async_main_wrapper)
    th.start()
    # run Flask server
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=9999)
    th.join()
```

Comment: @orie great to hear it

Comment: This worked for me - using Dash as an app rather than Flask.

Comment: Can you elaborate why it is bad design? I.e. what are the risks?

Comment: @SterlingButters when the answer was written there was no "native" support for `asyncio` code in Flask, as far as I heard (I do not work with Flask for 1.5 years now) they added it in some way https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/async-await/ . So why it is bad? It is bad that asyncio eventloop works in one Thread. You can create more that one asyncio eventloop in another Thread, but it will decrease performance of your app instead. The same story with asyncio in one Thread + http requests handling in other threads. You just get worse performance.

Comment: @SterlingButters so asyncio http framework should be used as follows: 1) one event loop in one thread will handle all requests 2) read/write file in Thread since it is not async operation 3) move all CPU bound tasks in child processes OR use message queue (e.g. RabbitMQ) and move the tasks to other microservices!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want it to run all in one process, the following worked for me:

```
from functools import partial
from threading import Thread    


partial_run = partial(app.run, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True, use_reloader=False)
t = Thread(target=partial_run)
t.start()
asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code running a dash app (collecting flight data - courtesy Jose Portilla - Udemy) + the threading to run the dash app and some tasks in async.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import asyncio
from threading import Thread


# Dash
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import requests
import plotly.graph_objects as go 


# ** Async Part **

async def some_print_task():
    """Some async function"""
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print("Some Task")


async def another_task():
    """Another async function"""
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        print("Another Task")


async def async_main():
    """Main async function"""
    await asyncio.gather(some_print_task(), another_task())


def async_main_wrapper():
    """Not async Wrapper around async_main to run it as target function of Thread"""
    asyncio.run(async_main())


# *** Dash Part ***:
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([

    # html.Div([
    #     html.Iframe(src="https://www.flightradar24.com",
    #                 height=500,width=200)
    # ]),
    html.Div([
        html.Pre(id='counter-text',children='Active Flights Worldwide'),
        dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph',style={'width':1200}),
        dcc.Interval(   id='interval-component',
                        interval=6000,
                        n_intervals=0)
    ])
])
counter_list = []

@app.callback(  Output('counter-text','children'),
                [Input('interval-component','n_intervals')])
def update_layout(n):
    url = "https://data-live.flightradar24.com/zones/fcgi/feed.js?faa=1&mlat=1&flarm=1&adsb=1&gnd=1&air=1&vehicles=1&estimated=1&stats=1"
    res = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})  # A fake header is necessary to access the site
    data = res.json()
    counter = 0
    for element in data["stats"]["total"]:
        counter += data["stats"]["total"][element]

    counter_list.append(counter)
    return "Active flights Worldwide: {}".format(counter)

@app.callback(  Output('live-update-graph','figure'),
                [Input('interval-component','n_intervals')])
def update_graph(n):
    fig = go.Figure(data=[
            go.Scatter(x=list(range(len(counter_list))),
                        y=counter_list,
                        mode='lines+markers')
    ])

    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run all async stuff in another thread
    th = Thread(target=async_main_wrapper)
    th.start()
    # run Flask server
    # app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=9999)
    app.run_server(debug=True)
    th.join()
```

Comment: How do you keep dash from starting two threads when `debug=True`?

Answer (score -1):

Run `run_dashboard` in a background thread. Ref to the [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-in-threads).

```py
async def run():
    await asyncio.gather(
        asyncio.to_thread(run_dashboard),
        main()
    )

asyncio.run(run())
```

**Note** that `asyncio.to_thread` is a new function in version 3.9.
For python version older than 3.9, copy the following code
[threads.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/threads.py).

Comment: didn't work for me. Can you check my post?

Comment: How is this supposed to work? `run_dashboard` is a coroutine, it must be `await` ed. A thread just can't do that. This would require redefining the coroutine as a regular function.