# Async Dash as a blocking coroutine as Thread? Never awaited

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I tried this using to_thread with python3.9.

I have blocking IO (Dash App) inside async loop.

This is from:

[Asyncio run Dash (Flask) server with another coroutine concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67206119/asyncio-run-dash-flask-server-with-another-coroutine-concurrently/68724732#68724732)

First solution works: Just runs a dash App inside async loop....

Example gather flight Data into a plot....

```
# from flask import Flask, jsonify
import asyncio
from threading import Thread


#Dash
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import requests
import plotly.graph_objects as go 


# ** Async Part **


async def some_print_task():
    """Some async function"""
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print("Some Task")


async def another_task():
    """Another async function"""
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        print("Another Task")


async def async_main():
    """Main async function"""
    await asyncio.gather(some_print_task(), another_task())


def async_main_wrapper():
    """Not async Wrapper around async_main to run it as target function of Thread"""
    asyncio.run(async_main())


# *** Dash Part ***:
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([

    # html.Div([
    #     html.Iframe(src="https://www.flightradar24.com",
    #                 height=500,width=200)
    # ]),
    html.Div([
        html.Pre(id='counter-text',children='Active Flights Worldwide'),
        dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph',style={'width':1200}),
        dcc.Interval(   id='interval-component',
                        interval=6000,
                        n_intervals=0)
    ])
])
counter_list = []

@app.callback(  Output('counter-text','children'),
                [Input('interval-component','n_intervals')])
def update_layout(n):
    url = "https://data-live.flightradar24.com/zones/fcgi/feed.js?faa=1&mlat=1&flarm=1&adsb=1&gnd=1&air=1&vehicles=1&estimated=1&stats=1"
    res = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})  # A fake header is necessary to access the site
    data = res.json()
    counter = 0
    for element in data["stats"]["total"]:
        counter += data["stats"]["total"][element]

    counter_list.append(counter)
    return "Active flights Worldwide: {}".format(counter)

@app.callback(  Output('live-update-graph','figure'),
                [Input('interval-component','n_intervals')])
def update_graph(n):
    fig = go.Figure(data=[
            go.Scatter(x=list(range(len(counter_list))),
                        y=counter_list,
                        mode='lines+markers')
    ])

    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run all async stuff in another thread
    th = Thread(target=async_main_wrapper)
    th.start()
    # run Flask server
    # app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=9999)
    app.run_server(debug=True)
    th.join()
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67306230/1579329

The second answer I cannot run: Seems more elegant. Errors below.

What am I missing?

Many thanks

```
import asyncio
import dash

async def main():
    print('In Main')
    # await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    
async def run_dashboard():
    app = dash.Dash()
    app.run_server('0.0.0.0', 5000, debug=False)
    print("Running Dash")

async def run():
    await asyncio.gather(
    asyncio.to_thread(run_dashboard),
    main()
)

asyncio.run(run())
```

And get the error that run_dashboard is not awaited.

: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'run_dashboard' was never awaited
handle = None  # Needed to break cycles when an exception occurs.

Comment: [The answer you alude to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67278347/5349916) just seems to be wrong. A thread cannot run a coroutine by itself.

Comment: A thread can run any object? A coroutine is an object, or am I wrong?

Comment: Essentially, I want dash inside a Flask app - i.e https://medium.com/@olegkomarov_77860/how-to-embed-a-dash-app-into-an-existing-flask-app-ea05d7a2210b What okomarov did. But with some async logic to feed the app .

Answer (score -1):

```
# from flask import Flask, jsonify
import asyncio
from threading import Thread

#Dash
import dash

# ** Async Part **
async def some_print_task():
    """Some async function"""
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print("Some Task")


async def another_task():
    """Another async function"""
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        print("Another Task")


async def async_main():
    """Main async function"""
    await asyncio.gather(some_print_task(), another_task())


def async_main_wrapper():
    """Not async Wrapper around async_main to run it as target function of Thread"""
    asyncio.run(async_main())

# *** Dash Part ***:
app = dash.Dash()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run all async stuff in another thread
    th = Thread(target=async_main_wrapper)
    th.start()
    app.run_server(debug=True)
    th.join()
```

How about that?