# Read in parallel and write sequentially?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have the following code which read and write for each `id` sequentially.

```
async def main():
    while id < 1000:
       data = await read_async(id) 
       await data.write_async(f'{id}.csv')
       id += 1
```

`read_async()` takes several minutes and `write_async()` takes less than one minute to run. Now I want to

1. Run `read_async(id)` in parallel. However, at most 3 calls can be run in parallel because of memory limitation.
2. `write_async` has to be run sequentially, i.e., `write_async(n+1)` cannot be run before `write_async(n)`.

Comment: Hi, I'm curious if my answer helped with the issue?

Comment: Yes, it should work. I haven't had a chance to implement it yet. (right now it still runs sequentially). My actually task is of a list of items instead `id` in `range(1000)`.

Comment: Makes sense; I've now edited the answer not to require ids to be numeric (it wasn't really necessary anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a queue and a fixed number of tasks for reading, and write from the main task. The main task can use an event to find out that new data is available from the readers and and a shared dict to get it from them. For example (untested):

```
async def reader(q, id_to_data, data_ready):
    while True:
        id = await q.get()
        data = await read_async(id) 
        id_to_data[id] = data
        data_ready.set()

async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    for id in range(1000):
        await q.put(id)

    id_to_data = {}
    data_ready = asyncio.Event()
    readers = [asyncio.create_task(reader(q, id_to_data, data_ready))
               for _ in 3]

    for id in range(1000):
       while True:
           # wait for the current ID to appear before writing
           if id in id_to_data:
               data = id_to_data.pop(id)
               await data.write_async(f'{id}.csv')
               break
               # move on to the next ID
           else:
               # wait for new data and try again
               await data_ready.wait()
               data_ready.clear()

    for r in readers:
        r.cancel()
```

Using a separate queue for results instead of the event wouldn't work because a queue is unordered. A priority queue would fix that, bit it would still immediately return the lowest id currently available, whereas the writer needs the *next* id in order to process all ids in order.