# Process items concurrently and write the results sequentially?

Tags: python, c#, asynchronous

The following Python code (from [Read in parallel and write sequentially?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65922160/read-in-parallel-and-write-sequentially)) processes (reads) the data for ID 0 to N. There readers run in parallel and it writes the result in the order of ID. How to implement it in **C#** efficiently?

```py
async def reader(q, id_to_data, data_ready):  # Multiple readers are run in parallel
    while True:
        id = await q.get()
        data = await read_async(id) 
        id_to_data[id] = data
        data_ready.set()

async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    for id in range(1000):
        await q.put(id)

    id_to_data = {}
    data_ready = asyncio.Event()
    readers = [asyncio.create_task(reader(q, id_to_data, data_ready))
               for _ in range(3)]

    for id in range(1000):
       while True:
           # wait for the current ID to appear before writing
           if id in id_to_data:
               data = id_to_data.pop(id)
               await data.write_async(f'{id}.csv')
               break
               # move on to the next ID
           else:
               # wait for new data and try again
               await data_ready.wait()
               data_ready.clear()

    for r in readers:
        r.cancel()
```

C#:

```
void main() {
    List<int> ids = get_IDs();
    ProcessAllIDs(ids);
}

async Task ProcessAllIDs(List<int> ids) {
    // A low efficient implementation
    for (var id in ids) {
        var result = await Process1(id); // Can be run concurrently
        await Process2(result); // Need to be run sequentially 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the example is in Python.

Comment: Usually there's little advantage to running IO operations in parallel - do you have _actual evidence_ (profiler reports, benchmarks, etc?) that demonstrate that doing IO like this in your Python program is actually faster overall?

Comment: @Dai, I've updated the question and changed "in parallel to concurrently".

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be to create a List of Tasks and then await in them in sequence:

```
var list = new List<Task<int>> { Calculate(2), Calculate(7), Calculate(19) };

foreach(var task in list)
{
  Console.WriteLine(await task);
}

static async Task<int> Calculate(int x)
{
  await Task.Delay(200);
  return x*x;
}
```

This will start 3 Tasks that calculate stuff simultaneously and then print the results in order.

So for your example, it would look like this:

```
async Task main() {
    List<int> ids = get_IDs();
    await ProcessAllIDs(ids);
}

async Task ProcessAllIDs(List<int> ids) {
    var tasks = ids.Select(id => Process1(id)).ToList();
    for (var t in tasks) {
        await Process2(await t); // Need to be run sequentially 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Calculate` function **needs** to invoke `SemaphoreSlim.Release()` inside a `finally` block, otherwise an unhandled exception in `Calculate` will mean that the semaphore count will never change and so other invocations (even if they don't have any exceptions or errors) will <del>block</del> await indefinitely at `await s.WaitAsync()`.

Comment: "You can use a semaphore to limit the concurrency of your calculation:" - I think a better approach is to use `Parallel.ForEach` rather than fiddling with `SemaphoreSlim` (and other synchronziation primitives) - or even use the simpler-yet `BlockingCollection` - though I'm unsure what the purpose of limiting concurrency is in this application.

Comment: Yes, I saw that in the linked question. will remove it from this answer

Comment: For parallelizing asynchronous work, the correct API is the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync), not the `Parallel.ForEach`. It's available only on .NET 6 and later though.