# How to run tkinter window parallel to other processes?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing

I have tkinter application that controlls as well as import values from a serial connection. I need two loops that run independently one for the serial connection and one for the main application of tkinter.

I tried doing that by using threading, from the answer in this link:
[Running infinite loops using threads in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23100704/running-infinite-loops-using-threads-in-python)
but the tkinter application was running very slow.
my code looked something like that.

```
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread

class Tkinter_Window(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        self.tkinter_window = tk.Tk()
        self.tkinter_window.mainloop()

class Serial_Connection(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        #serial connection should go here#
        pass

class Some_Other_Process(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        #any other needed processes#
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Tkinter_Window()
    Serial_Connection()
    Some_Other_Process()
    while True:
        pass
```

however the tkinter application was too slow. after searching for the reason I read that multiprocessing might work better in my case. I appreciate any opinions about how to run parallel processes while being able to optimise how much processing power they take.

I also tried multiprocessing https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html but I couldn't figure out how to run the loop of the main tkinter application.

Comment: You should not run `tkinter` in a child thread.  Run it in the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing something like using `tkinter_window.update()` regularly in your main code instead of mainloop. Hope that's helpful!